# how do I find a coordinates given a number in Spiral pattern?

Tags: python, algorithm, spiral

given a spiral of numbers in which the numbers are arranged in the form of a triangle, i need to write a function that takes a number and returns the coordinates of this number

```
           15
           16 14
           17 3  13
           18 4  2  12
           19 5  0> 1  11
           20 6  7  8  9  10
           21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
```

for example 17 the result is (-2, 2) in x and y

I already did a similar task, but there the spiral was square and the program received coordinates (x, y) as input and returned a number. in short, there I calculated the size of the square and the offset.

I will be glad for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR: Working code at the bottom**

First consider how many numbers you have in each triangle:

- The first contains 3 numbers in each edge
- The second contains 6 numbers in each edge
- The third contains 9 numbers in each edge

So there is our pattern. Triangle `i` contains `9i` numbers and the before we do anything else we need to divide our number by `9` and find the [triangle root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Triangular_roots_and_tests_for_triangular_numbers) of the result (and round it down):

[image]

Once you figure out the right triangle, there are three things left to do:

- You need to find the starting point

This is trivial as the "last point" of triangle `i` will always be `(2i, i)`.

- You need to find the right edge

You already know that your triangle has `i`-long edges so by taking the sum of your remainders (from the original `divmod` and from rooting) and dividing it by 3 you can find the right edge.

- You need to find the right point on this edge

This bit is trivial - you have 3 types of edges, horizontal, vertical and diagonal. Depending on the type you have to apply your "final residual value" to the "origin of the edge":

- `(-r, -r)` for the diagonal
- `(0, r)` for the vertical
- `(r, 0)` for the horizontal

Relative to the max point of the **previous** triangle to get to the right edge you just have to apply a cumulative sum of these transpositions:

- `(-r, -r)` for the diagonal
- `(-i, -i+r)` for the vertical
- `(-i+r, 0)` for the horizontal

Putting it all together

```py
def triangle_root(x):
    return int((8 * x + 1) ** 0.5 - 1) // 2

def spiral(v):
    # Identify the current triangle
    i = min(v, triangle_root(max(0, (v - 1) / 9)) + 1)
    # Compute the coordinates for the max value of this triangle
    xi, yi = 2 * i, i
    # Compute the point index in the current triangle
    # In other words, subtract the previous triangle max
    r = v - 9 * (i - 1) * i // 2
    # Compute the edge length for the current triangle
    length = 3 * max(1, i)
    # Compute the current edge and the location in that edge
    edge, r = divmod(r, length)
    # Apply the relevant transform depending on the edge
    if edge == 1: # vertical
        dx, dy = -length, r - length
    elif edge == 2: # horizontal
        dx, dy = r - length, 0
    else: # diagonal
        dx, dy = -r, -r
    
    return xi + dx, yi + dy
```

Comment: This works perfectly, except for the `y` sign, i have altered `return x, -y`

Comment: Right, I used "programming" coordinates, rather than mathematical so flip according to your needs :)

Answer (score 1):

No code, but I would start with something like the following:

1. rearrange the numbers to understand the structure of the triangle-spiral

```
 0
 1  2
 3  4  5
 6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
...
```

Please note that if we take complete lines and arrange them back to spiral form, we will arrive at complete triangles.

2. Add the coordinates (I hope I understand them correctly.)

```
0   0                      0, 0
1   1  2                   1, 0    0, 1
2   3  4  5               -1, 2   -1, 1  -1, 0

3   6  7  8  9            -1,-1    0,-1   1,-1   2,-1
4  10 11 12 13 14          3,-1    2, 0   1, 1   0, 2  -1, 3 
5  15 16 17 18 19 20      -2, 4   -2, 3  -2, 2  -2, 1  -2, 0  -2,-1

6  21 22 23 24 25 26 27   -2,-2    ...
...
```

I have also added a row number `r` in front: three rows form a complete "turn" in the spiral.

You can see the coordinate pattern  within the rows, it depends of course on how it can be divided by 3:

- rows divisible by 3 start at `-r/3, -r/3` and increment `x`
- rows with remainder 1 start at `2*(r-1)/3+1, -(r-1)/3`, decrement `x` and increment `y`
- rows with remainder 2 start at `-(r+1)/3, 2*(r+1)/3` and decrement `y`

3. Figure out in which row we actually are

The last number `n` in row `r` is "`n = {sum i for i from 0 to r+1} = (r+1)(r+2)/2`". We solve this for `r` and arrive at:

```
r = -3/2 + sqrt(9/4 + 2n)
```

Only the positive solution is relevant.

If we insert a number `n` like 12, we get `r = 3.6` which means we are somewhere in row 4 as expected, please check the row numbers.

4. Put things together

- Calculate the current row number.
- Calculate the position within the row by subtracting the last number of the previous row.
  This is `n_prev = r*(r+1)/2` in general and `n_prev = 4*5/2 = 10` in the example with `n=12`.
  The position within the row for the example is `pos = 12-10 = 2`
- Calculate the remainder of the current row number on division by 3. For the example we have `4 = 3*1 + 1`
- Now calculate the coordinates by selecting the appropriate formula. For the example we have row `4`, remainder `1` and position `2`, so we need

```
[2*(r-1)/3+1, -(r-1)/3] + pos*[-1, 1] = [2*3/3+1, -3/3] + [-2,2] = [1,1]
```

Again, please check with your initial spiral-triangle.